# THREE.SpriteAlignment showing up as undefined

Tags: three.js

After updating from three.js r62Dev to r64 or r64Dev I am receiving the following error.

```
 var radarMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: radarTexture2, useScreenCoordinates: true, alignment: THREE.SpriteAlignment.topLeft } );
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'topLeft' of undefined.

Has any one else experienced this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`SpriteMaterial.alignment` and `SpriteMaterial.useScreenCoordinates` have been removed from Threejs. See the release history: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases.

Sprites are now rendered in the scene just like any other object.

If you want to create a heads-up display (HUD), the work-around is to overlay a second scene of sprites, rendered with an orthographic camera.

See http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html for an example of how to do that.

three.js r.64

Comment: Thanks for the update. Won't this change be less efficient since it now requires an additional render pass to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: The new approach is cleaner.

Comment: still though updating Three.js should not break existing code, if the property was deprecated wouldn't it still work (even if it's not the preferred method)? It appears it was removed from the library altogether, which is not the meaning of "deprecated" from my understanding

Comment: @ekcrisp Good point. Be aware, however, that three.js is in _alpha_, so breakage can be expected to happen every now and then.

Comment: @WestLangley Got it. The fix was easy enough, and I agree with the change. I'm surprised three is still in alpha given how widely used and feature rich it is, do you know if a beta release is in the foreseeable future?

Comment: @ekcrisp Maybe probably?

Comment: Can I add spritey directly in the same scene and not adding the orthographic camera?

Comment: @StefanoMaglione You need to make a new post if you have a question.