# Update three.js rev 62 to 63 - Error: the function SpriteAlignment is no longer present

Tags: three.js

In three.js r63 there is no trace of function THREE.SpriteAlignment.topLeft. How can I remedy in this new version?

According to the migration page and release notes there was no change in this sense.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601102/three-spritealignment-showing-up-as-undefined

Comment: Can You post me a simple example on how I can migrate this function?

Comment: See the three.js example referenced in the above link. You are going to have to study that example and figure out a way to adapt the same technique to your use case. Sorry, I can't do that for you.

Comment: What I can not understand is why the sprites are centered only on the y anz z axes. While they are not centered respect to the x axis.

Comment: My problem is that the sprites unlike other objects, which rotate properly around the z axis, they follow strange trajectories different from those expected.

Comment: If you are having problems, you need to make a new post, show your code or a live example, and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: Hello! I followed your advice: I opened a new post at the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810163/sprites-incorrect-positioning?noredirect=1#comment33006287_21810163

Comment: Sorry, I would like to be able to help everyone debug their code, but I can no longer do that. I can answer questions about three.js.