# Sprites incorrect positioning

Tags: javascript, three.js

I use Three.js ver. 65 The browsers are Firefox ver. 27.0.1 and Chrome 32.0.1700.107 m. I tested the app on Windows Xp, 7 and 8.

My problems are the following (http://jsfiddle.net/j8DN6/4/):

1) What I can not understand is why the sprites are not centered respect to the center of the Cartesian axes.
I.e: 
    `spritey.position = (0, 0, 0);`

2) The sprites unlike other objects, which rotate properly around the z axis, they follow strange trajectories different from those expected.

3) If I turn the 3d radar-chart along the x-axis the sprites, which were in front of the circles of the radar chart, changing position by moving back.

I hope I was clear. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What a wizardous script you have in the fiddle? FF crashes...

Comment: I have no problem with FF... Have you the same problem with Chrome?

Comment: Actually the crash happened only at the first time when I opened the fiddle, on the second load everything worked fine. No problems with Chrome.

Comment: Ok! Very well! Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understood your question correctly, but you're creating asymmetric triangles, hence they are not centered [(A fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/tqVUd/).

Comment: The triangles are radar charts... The vertex of the triangles rotate correctly around the axes center, also the Deltas axexs, the the writing "DeltaC" ecc... Only the sprites are non centered (the numbered boxes)...
I wish that the sprites were placed close to the vertices of the triangles, and revolved with them.

Comment: So what's your question?