# Threejs add labels

Tags: javascript, three.js

Following some  [previous post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601102/three-spritealignment-showing-up-as-undefined) I am trying to add labels in my canvas.
I made a second scene and second camera to overlap my labels on first scene.

```
this.sceneOrtho = new THREE.Scene();//for labels
this.scene = new THREE.Scene();// for Geometry

//camera for geometry
var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth-5, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight-5;
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20;
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
var r = 4, phi = Math.PI/4, theta = Math.PI/4;
this.camera.position.set(r*Math.cos(phi)*Math.sin(theta),r*Math.sin(phi), r*Math.cos(phi)*Math.cos(theta));
this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

// camera for labels
this.cameraOrtho = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR );
this.cameraOrtho.position.z = 10;
```

I also added THREE.Sprite object to the scene `sceneOrtho.add(spritey);`
 and rendered `this.model.clearScene(this.scene);
    this.model.populateScene(this.scene,this.sceneOrtho);//<--------
    this.renderer.clear();
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.renderer.clearDepth();
    this.renderer.render( this.sceneOrtho, this.cameraOrtho );`

but I can see only the geometries and not my labels.
Here there is a live [example](http://www.felpone.netsons.org/) click on button test to see it.

Comment: You are being too quick to post here. Ask questions that are useful to others. Ask questions about three.js, and avoid help-me-debug-my-code questions. You should be able to find your own mistake in this case.

Comment: You are right, but seriously I cannot find what is wrong in this code @WestLangley

Comment: Maybe this example is what you're after? http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_pdb.html

Answer (score -2):

I guess scene is rendering right, but your orthographic camera is looking in bad direction. I don't see setting `lookAt` for your ortho camera.

And yes as @westlangley write, this is not useful for others.